# UWP Complex TextBlock foreground

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I nead to realize foreground like this. How can i do it by Xaml or from C# code in my UWP app?
[image: Complex foreground]

Comment: What did you try? We can't give you answer to that

Comment: I only googled. I thought to use ImageBrush for foreground, but i decedid that is not good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LinearGradientBrush` can meet your need.

```xml
<Page.Resources>
   <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TestGradient" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
       <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
           <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.0"/>
           <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.3"/>
           <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.3"/>
           <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.8"/>
           <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.8"/>
           <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
       </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
   </LinearGradientBrush>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="535" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Black" Foreground="{StaticResource TestGradient}"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: 5ee687ca-82a4-4013-8e21-9b523f01cec3.png]

Comment: Super! Thank you